# Pandas_datareader not working in script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Why isn't Pandas datareader working when called from script?

If I enter it in the python shell line-by-line (see below) it works as advertised. But when I an run it as a script it crashes; "python3 script.py " (errors below):

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 27)
f = web.DataReader("F", 'yahoo-dividends', start, end)
f 


File "pandas.py", line 1, in <module>
import pandas_datareader.data as web
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas_datareader-0.2.1-py3.4.egg/pandas_datareader/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from .data import (get_components_yahoo, get_data_famafrench, get_data_google, get_data_yahoo,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas_datareader-0.2.1-py3.4.egg/pandas_datareader/data.py", line 7, in <module>
from pandas_datareader.google.daily import GoogleDailyReader
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas_datareader-0.2.1-py3.4.egg/pandas_datareader/google/daily.py", line 1, in <module>
from pandas_datareader.base import _DailyBaseReader
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas_datareader-0.2.1-py3.4.egg/pandas_datareader/base.py", line 9, in <module>
from pandas import to_datetime
File "/home/pi/python/pandas.py", line 1, in <module>
import pandas_datareader.data as web
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'data'
```

Comment: Can you rename the file and try again?

Comment: @joris, do you mean renaming script.py to something like test.py?

Comment: One quick note, the shell that works  is the idle3, but when I start the shell from the command, like the same command fails....

Comment: Sorry, no, I meant `pandas.py`. It seems you have a file `pandas.py` in your current working directory that it tries to import instead of pandas itself.

Answer (score 0):

@joris, you hit the nail on the head. The problem was the pandas.py and pandas.pyc files. After removing them everything seems to be back to norma